# A few questions about Islam and Allah - I don't understand

Tags: salat, allah, islamic-philosophy, sex, conversion

I have a few questions about Islam and Allah which I would like to ask. I have been quite frustrated for some time now as to why/how/etc... in regards to these questions. Ok so here goes:

**1)**  Why does Allah need us to pray? Allah is the almighty, powerful, perfect and wise one. So why does he need us to kneel down everyday and pray? Can't we just say "I believe in you Allah" and leave it at that? I believe in God, but I don't see why I have to prey everyday? Especially how you have to do it 5 times a day (or 3 if your Shite Muslim).

**2)** The devil is horrible and is always trying to ruin everything, I understand this, but God is obviously the number one most powerful. So can't he just click his fingers and get rid of the devil immediately? If he did that, maybe all these weapons/oil companies/bankers wouldn't go around the world starting wars and killing innocent people (like in Palestine)???

**3)** How come Islam has lots of rules regarding sex? Like why do you have to be married? And why is anal not allowed? God loves us all right? Why would something like this matter? In fact isn't one of the rules of God, is that we should populate the Earth? That's one of the reasons God created the Earth, so that we, his people, could live on it and breed and so on????

**4)** So Islam allows Christianity and Judaism. So how come if a Muslim converts to one of those religions, he/she is to be killed? I thought those religions are allowed by Islam?

**5)** What does God do all day? Do he check on all his creations or something? Does he eat food? Does he have an iPhone? Does he go swimming? Etc...???

**6)** Lastly, if someone is just good all their life, then isn't that good enough for God? Personally I'm a hard working young man, I believe in honesty, and being respectful towards each other, etc.... Can't that just be good enough?

Thanks for your time and patience, I hope you can help me with this, because these questions have been in my mind for ages and its made me quite angry.

Comment: First, there are already answers of all these questions separately. I suggest you to search a little bit, in Google or in this site, because they are very known. Second, this is a quick question-answer site. You shouldn't ask broad and multiple questions in one question according to site rules.

Comment: I don't want to close your first question, because I sincerely believe that you are curious about these issues. But others probably will, so please search for these questions separately, and if you don't satisfied with the answers you would find, then ask them separately.

Comment: I know this may be against the rules, but perhaps, we can leave this open and edit his questions with the proper links to what was already answered.    Then we can answer the one's that were never asked.  Yet, some may not understand the answers properly also and need further clarification.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

May God Bless you, Dan.

I think that a common theme in all of your questions is "why does God..." or "why is God..." But I believe that we shouldn't try to look at things from God's perspective; this is because God is infinite and we are finite. To try to look at things from God's perspective is to ask your brain to do what it can't and it also inherently leads to us belittling God.

With regards to worship and what Allah asks us to do, I would always keep in mind what Allah told Adam "And when guidance comes to from Me, then whoever follows My Guidance, no fear is upon them nor will they be sad." What this means is that Allah asks us to do what's good for us. It's not that we are 'serving Allah'...because He has no need for our service...it is that these acts of worship are actually good for us.

That said, I would rephrase your question: "Why does Allah need us to pray" as: "Why do we need to pray?" Indeed, asking the right question is half the way to the answer, as they say. From looking at the question from this point of you, you see that it's really about how prayer benefits us. How when we are sad throughout the day, when we are faced with the difficulties that this life puts in our path, we stop and remember our Creator. We stop and remember our true purpose and the fact that Allah has our back whenever we turn to Him. It is as the Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him said: "My happiness is in prayer."

(2) This life is not a 'battlefield' between God and the devil. As you said, if God were to will it, the devil would be gone. This life is only a training ground for the believers of God; it is place where they interact with evil only to know that evil *is* evil and to avoid it. It is a place where we learn that nearness to Allah is where happiness is and distance from Allah is where sadness is. So you see there's a mercy even in the existence of the devil: it is our fear of evil and our inherent disliking of evil that makes us run towards Allah.

(3) There aren't that many rules for sex except perhaps that you have to be married and that, yes, anal sex is not allowed. The main reason that we cannot have sex outside of marriage is because 'Allah said so.' But let me put it to you this way: 
The family structure is *extremely* important. A good society is built upon strong institutions and strong institutions is built upon strong people and strong people come from strong families. If you think about the sources of some of society's most immoral acts, it is often, in part, due to weak family structures. When the family is strong the whole society is strong. Marriage is the foundation of the family. It isn't about marriage per se. It's about the commitment. 
Oh, and about anal sex, it is perhaps one of the most dangerous kinds of sex (and perhaps this is the wisdom behind Allah forbidding it). See, for example, http://www.webmd.com/sex/anal-sex-health-concerns

(4) A number of scholars have pointed to the verse in the Qur'an "There is no forcing in religion" (2:256) as proof that people who leave the faith of Islam are not to be forced back in. Perhaps at one point in history, leaving Islam was synonymous with leaving Islam to join the political enemies of Islam, in which case it is more a matter of 'treason' than 'leaving the faith.'

(5) Allah is not like anything that we can perceive.

(6) Being a good person is excellent, but I would consider the fact that our hearts yearn for what is beyond this world. Our hearts desire the eternal and they desire to know what is beyond merely the physical world. Disbelief is: silencing the calling of our hearts. Once again, it isn't about Allah needing us to believe, it is that we need to believe. Your asking these questions is indicative that you want to know, that you believe there's something out there, that there's more to it than what we see now. If we follow our hearts in this matter, we will undoubtedly find Allah.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Really helpful. Ok I guess I should start looking into praying and so on. I just don't know where to start.

Comment: Hi Dan. It's great that you're keen on starting to pray God. Do you have any books about Islam or have you read any good/articles or heard any good lectures? I can point you to a couple of good resources if you're interested.

Comment: Sorry for my late response, yeah if you could point me in the right direction that would be great. What kind of resources can I start reading to learn more about Islam. Also do Muslims have to read the Arabic version of the Quran or can they read the english version?

Answer (score 3):

> quest 1 . Why does Allah need us to pray?

ans 1 . allah did not need us to pray at all.

> quest 2.The devil is horrible and is always trying to ruin everything,
>   I understand this, but God is obviously the number one most powerful.
>   So can't he just click his fingers and get rid of the devil
>   immediately?

ans 2. When iblees disobeyed Allah azawajjal, he then asked Allah to give him time till day of judgement to deviate mankind, in order to show Allah that we are not worth what were given(status).

> quest 3.How come Islam has lots of rules regarding sex? Like why do
>   you have to be married? And why is anal not allowed?

ans 3. like the constitution of your country have lot of rules islaam have lot of rules not just for sex but for every aspect of life.
       rules are made just to make sure you did not harm any other fellow being. this is the rason anal is not allowed.

> quest 4. So Islam allows Christianity and Judaism. So how come if a
>   Muslim converts to one of those religions, he/she is to be killed? I
>   thought those religions are allowed by Islam?

ans 4. Christianity and Judaism are also the religion of book. but as the time passed these book are currupted by humans. , that is why allah sent last and final prophet with quran.
       for easy understanding you can think islaam as the latest version of software by allah till date.:).

> ques 5. What does God do all day? Do he check on all his creations or
>   something? Does he eat food? Does he have an iPhone? Does he go
>   swimming? Etc...???

ans 5. nobody knows what God  does all day as he is infinite and beyond our imagination. but he definately does not need food/iphone/swimming.

> ques 6. Lastly, if someone is just good all their life, then isn't
>   that good enough for God? Personally I'm a hard working young man, I
>   believe in honesty, and being respectful towards each other, etc....
>   Can't that just be good enough?

ans 6 .good enough or not nobody can judge because it is the matter between you and allah. but i can tell you that apart from honesty, being respectfull and hard working  you need to fulfill your duties towards your parents/family/neighbour/orphans and other fellow beings.

Comment: I appreciate your response which you endeavor to provide them in short. God Bless You, for presenting such nice answer. و من الله توفیق

Answer (score 0):

I know you want a full direct answers but this isn't the matter here and let me answer your Qs.

1- Allah wants from us to believe in him by doing not by saying, maybe your saying that believe is actually kinda of doing, but these r rules made by Allah, for me, I'm not praying all time because I'm kinda lazy or not clean enough to pray.

2- Okay, this is confusing but if You see it clearly god created a pure universe and we did all the mess, and of course he can destroy the devils and demons instantly but we r not here to live such as easy life, Allah said in his book : we made the human to live hard

3- yeah you have to marry to start a family , take care of ur kids, be serious  about family things because if u did the opposite, imagine what will happen, a girl deliver a baby , baby live and grow with broken and frustrated family, start to break bad and doing bad things with no rules to bound them for doing wrong.

4- No one will be killed for that, and Allah said in his Quran: if want to believe, then believe, and if u want to disbelieve then disbelieve..

5- I don't know what u mean by this but he's watching us anyway.

6- i don't think like other people who are thinking like Muslims people are only allowed to go to heaven and things like that, because if that happened there will be a lot of people will be oppressed...

Answer (score 0):

A cool question of a common man. As I can't cover all the stuff in just 1 answer, rest *"Seek and ye shall find"* - Jesus(pbuh)... by searching around in this site and Google (hey you can use Bing too, don't forget).

1. Suppose you help someone in need and you expect to hear "Thank you very much! That was so kind of you!" from the person who took your help(I'm not telling you to expect that now, for your rewards will be in paradise). Many places in Qur'an we can see "[little thanks do you give](http://quran.com/7/10)" emphasizing that we give due credits to the one who helped us continue our life in a smooth way.
2. [God's word took effect](http://quran.com/11/118-119), so wait until the day of judgement.
3. Same thing as emphasized by [No_NAME](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/23851/11938), don't end up like the people of Noah(pbuh) or the people of Lot(pbuh) i.e. not to make this a sole adulterous generation. And a low level answer could be 'One would feel bad if he finds his wife hanging around with some other guy'.
4. One is already a Christian and Jew per 'se by being a Muslim, one need not convert to their religion, [but be careful](http://quran.com/2/109). The thing is, Muslims are trying to become perfect Christians and Jews indeed by not repeating the mistakes already made by them. Moreover, community influence matters above all.
5. I'll help you formulate more questions, Which OS does God use Linux or Windows 10? in which language does he code, C++ or Python or Java? how does he handle so many threads almost infinite? what is his processing power like how many GHtz? How many servers does he have? What is the data transfer rate across the network?

   - One simple answer, **beyond the scope of Humans and Jinns**.
6. A very common question with one answer.

> As for those who disbelieve, their deeds are like a mirage in a desert. The thirsty one thinks it to be water, until he comes up to it, he finds it to be nothing, but he finds Allah with him, Who will pay him his due (Hell). And Allah is Swift in taking account. (Qur'an 24:39)

Trust Allah and he will reward beyond the earthly temporary things with super cool luxurious things in paradise which are permanent.

May the creator guide us all.

(May Allah forgive me if I've said something wrong)

Comment: Being a computer science uni student myself, I love your answer for question 5 :)

Answer (score 0):

Things can be evaluated in different ways.According to me

1)If anybody pay you you will work for him 7 or 8 hours a day.Allah gives you eyes,ears,strength,brain and lot that nobody can give.So we have to thank him.He only asks that. 
   Each muslim have an aim in there life.In a day pray 5 time.In one year fast one month like that.What is your aim.Live till Death

2)God created heaven and hell.There should be somebody to go there.devil rises from pride of human.

3)Allah said "I have completed your religion".A complete religion have rule for all things that man have to face.

4)Taking the life himself and others without reason is not allowed in islam. Human can select his religion.God will asks you why you take that on day of judgement.Question is wrong.

5)God creates sun.without sun day and night doesn't exist.Time is only for humans not for god.Don't compare human with god.After creating the whole universe allah is sitting in his arash(allah's seat).

6)human have to thank there god.For that they have to find him by studying each religion.If you doesn't know about islam and muhammed(s) allah will forgive you.If you heard about this religion you have to answer allah what stop you from accepting islam.(study qur'an and life of muhammed(s) not current life of muslims)
   Consider an example that you created a robot by hard working.After that robot says you are not the creator somebody else created him.What do you feel.????