# Why should we obey ALL Islam rules , when we see some of them are useless?

Tags: sharia, freedom-of-belief, freedom

Why should we do something only because it's in religious?

Suppose rights between men and women. Did anyone decide to be a man or woman himself/herself ? Then why should we separate their rights? Beside this fact that equality of rights are executed in western world without any problem.

Also suppose expressions about have dog, eat pig, drink wine and so many other things that are currently usual in western world and NOTHING wrong happen about that.

Living in this way and obey only because ISLAM say so is completely opposite the freedom of thinking. It's a Blind Life.

Does Islam have any defense for its incompatibility with facts and things that we do opposite its rules but has no harm and mistake in it?

If Islam base is on thinking, why should we obey them only because it says so?

Comment: Because Muslims [believe](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=2&verse=285), they have to [obey](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=33&verse=36)

Comment: As with any other religion it's belief based, not fact. However, most of the rules and rituals followed predates Islam.

Comment: @azam It's a Blind Life.

Comment: See also http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/23850/9123 & http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24041/9123

Comment: @azam Thinking is basis of Islam. Quran says "لا اکراه فی الدین" and it means thinking is above any religion. Don't believe blindly my friend. It will back you off from thinking and making ideas, Plz...

Comment: @HOPE I have the same question, so I am just adding my novice thoughts here and not answering it. I believe the Quran is a book of guidance and not the book of rules. The guidance is provided with instances or stories which happened in the past or during that time so that we can lead a more virtuous life based on it. So, this is my thought, eras have passed by, things are no longer the same as in past or in that time, there are no slaves any longer etc, etc. So, we should not follow blindly rather decide rationally.

Comment: @ToUsIf Such a great vision. I believe so.

Answer (score 2):

Islam means submission. You submit your will to the will of Allah out of conviction that He knows better, and He loves for his product (You) the best. 
Every one is free to believe in Islam or not. Half belief is not Islam. New converts have to declare in front of witnesses that they believed in Allah without a partners or equals. He is the creator of every thing other than Him.

When your car breaks and you like to restore it to perfect order, take it to the dealer (the manufacturer who made you is Allah). 
If you want your car to perform at its best, then use the manufacturer's users manual (Quran) and when it breaks use the manufacturer's service manual.

You are not only submitting your car to the One who is more qualified than you, but you also submitting your life, and your health to a human like you. You check the yellow pages, read his credentials then once you "Believe in him" you submit your will to your doctor. 
You do not ask for the chemical formula when he writes for you a prescription. 
You submit your will when the doctor decides that you need an operation. 
You pay for extra doctors when your doctor admits his lack of knowledge and asks to bring others in a medical consults. 
On the bed of the operation, you do not even read the whole disclaimer, and you sign that if the doctor makes a mistake, and you die, then he will not be sued. 
After all of that submission, you like to pick and chose from the instructions of the One who created you, not just studied 7 years in a medical school. 
If you feel this way, then check you faith of submission.

Comment: Believe mean obey blindly ?! I'm searching for some defending state from Islam (Quran or Sunnat) that distinguish our blind obey and thoughtful obey.

Comment: @HOPE, I agree with you to some extent that it is not good to ... blindly, but the issue of submitting as dear Nabil saidl can be considered as a significant point too (and I appreciate Nabil's answer somewhat)